# Spring @Transactional usage with parallelStreams

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I have @Transactional method with big logic inside it. In different parts of it there are parallel streams that update entity objects in repositories which are changed before parallel stream.

As example:

```
    @Transactional
    public void someTransactionalMethod(int number) {
        SomeClass foo = someRepository.getById(number);
        foo.setState("PROCESSED");  
        //............................................................
        //..................some logic................................
        //............................................................

            getData().entrySet().parallelStream().forEach(entry -> {
                  // some heavy operation
                  someRepository.save(foo);
                  // some logic
            }
   }
```

The operation of saving attached object in parallel stream brings a big varity of Hibernate runtime exception as The session is closed etc. The problem is that transactions is thread local in Spring Data Jpa. But I have not find the solution how we can save entity objects from the other thread. Because in my case using one thread is very slowly to do the heavy operations that can be done fast in parallel. And at the other hand I can't delete save methods from parallel stream because the logic will be broken. What is the solution, how can we combine parallelStreams and save attached objects in transaction?

Comment: could you save foo after the parallelStream? could you use update queries to update foo? the entries in the parallelStream do they modify shared data in foo?

Comment: No, i can t save after the parallel stream. Yes, the entries modify shared data. I can use update queries

Comment: could you say why you can not save after the parallel stream? if the entries modify shared foo data does not this mean that foo.sharedField is set to x than foo.sharedField is set to y and so on and every entry in the persists the changes. in this case what should be the final value for foo.sharedField? x or y?